# Prove the following integral is convergent.

Tags: calculus

$$\int_0^1\frac{\log(t)}{(1 - t)^{3/2}} dt$$
My confusion is that this integral has two singularities (at $0$ and $1$). How do I apply the comparison test to this type of integral.

Comment: hint: divide the integral in two parts in order to treat the two singularities separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrand function behaves like $\log(t)$ in a right neighbourhood of the origin and like
$$ \frac{\log(1-(1-t))}{(1-t)^{3/2}}\approx -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}$$
in a left neighbourhood of $1$. Since both $\log(t)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ are integrable in a right neighbourhood of the origin, your integral is finite. You also have
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log t}{(1-t)^{3/2}}\,dt = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1-t)}{t^{3/2}}\,dt = -\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{n-3/2}}{n}\,dt =-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2}{n(2n-1)}$$
where the last series is absolutely convergent, and convergent to $\color{red}{-4\log 2}$ by partial fraction decomposition.